# php randomly losing array entries

Tags: php, arrays

Following an SQL call, php is storing a 2D assoc array with a list of services. I'm then splitting this into two different arrays (one for services that match a "friendly" name (i.e; predefined service), and another for unspecified services.

During this process, php seems to be randomly throwing out array entries - before the split even begins.

Code:

```
        $tmp_results_friendly = array();
        $tmp_results_uncategorised = array();
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            //var_dump($result);
            if ((int)$result['friendly_service_id'] != 0) {
                $tmp_results_friendly[] = $result;
            } else {
                $tmp_results_uncategorised[] = $result;
            }
        }
```

At the point of the commented-out var_dump, entries can go missing at random. A var_dump of $result will show everything. It's typically services that have a friendly_id which is not equal to 0 which go missing.

There are no duplicates in the array, nor is there any over-writing of entries in there. a var_dump just before the foreach loop will return everything - but it seems to just straight out vanish when we enter the foreach loop.

I'm at a loss as to what could cause this - does anyone have any idea?

**Edit: added additional code to check array length;**

```
        $tmp_results_friendly = array();
        $tmp_results_uncategorised = array();
        echo "<br/>Results count is: " . count($results);
        $i = (int) 0;
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            //var_dump($result);
            $i++;
            if ((int)$result['friendly_service_id'] != 0) {
                $tmp_results_friendly[] = $result;
            } else {
                $tmp_results_uncategorised[] = $result;
            }
        }
        echo "<br/>Counted in foreach is: {$i}";
```

results from this;

```
Results count is: 17
Counted in foreach is: 16
```

I also serialised the arrays before, and after the foreach; prior to the foreach, again we're seeing 17 results. After, 16. One is going missing - no change in structure, format, no special characters, or otherwise.

Comment: Instead of a var_dump at the beginning of your foreach can you proove things go missing? Run a `count` on the `$results` before it goes into the foreach, and during. Also you can use `!==` to ensure that the array changes. Can you show us an example of data being lost?

Comment: Instead of the `(int) $result['id'] != 0` try `!empty($result['id'])`, as they have the same effect.  Other than that, a little more code above, or context, may help.  Try an IDEOne example with minimal code that reproduces (an array with values, etc).

Comment: @Mike; the else{} statement should throw everything that doesn't match into the uncategorised array anyway; nothing should be lost.

@Catharsis: added code to check this; adding to main question now (too long for comment)

Comment: Post the `var_dump` of the `$results`

Comment: @WesFoster ; can't, the results are under DPA. The structure of all results are identical - with no duplicates.

Comment: @eoghan - `(int) $val != 0` is roughly 4 times slower than `!empty($val)` (3.89 times slower, to be exact) in my limited tests.  Granted, to see this clearly I had to run the test on 100 sequential evaluations in a loop of 10,000 times inside a greater loop of 100 (all to clear noise), but `!empty($val)` was consistently faster by 3-4 times.  Not a big deal, but not bad knowledge to keep in mind while coding.  As for the DPA, can make a minimal array that reproduces, with obfuscated data?  We don't need the full array or values, just enough that reproduces.

Comment: @Eoghan - Just tried a few variations, and `(int) $val != 0` is actually over 10 times slower when dealing with string values.  So, yeah.  Anyway, more example code/data and I hope we can help.